# Is there a way to manage "task dependency" using only Webpack

Tags: webpack, gulp

I'm switching from Gulp/Bower to an only Webpack configuration and I'd like to know if I can, with Webpack, do as Gulp is doing: "task dependencies".

For exemple in Gulp I have a task like this :

```
gulp.task('pngSprite', ['svgSprite'], function() {
    return gulp.src(joli.build + '/assets/svg/sprite.svg')
        .pipe(plugins.svg2png())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(joli.build + '/assets/svg/'));
});
```

So `pngSprite` wait for `svgSprite` to be finished.

Can I have the same behavior with Webpack and how?